# I cannot open the message and email apps? Nokia 635

Tags: email, messaging, windows-mobile, lumia-635

I have a Nokia 635 phone. It will not open the message app (texting) or the email app and whenever I press their icons it just bounces immediately to the start screen. The emails show up in the notifications but whenever I click them it also bounces back to the start screen. Text messages aren't showing up at all in notifications. Any ideas on how to fix it? I really need it to work soon.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your phone?

Comment: Is your phone running Windows Phone 8 or Windows 10 Mobile?